# datetime timestamp crossing month boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am creating a series of timestamps for noon on consecutive days from today onwards. This works fine, except for when attempting to cross the boundary from September:

```
import time
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

today = datetime.today()
str_date = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')
int_date = int(str_date)

for i in range(0, 7):

    run_date = str(int_date + int(i))
    string_datetime = ''.join((str(run_date), '120000'7))
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(string_datetime, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').timestamp()
    t = str(timestamp).replace('.0', '')
    print(run_date, t)
```

In which case I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/myfolder/myfile.py", line 12, in <module>
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(string_datetime, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S').timestamp()
  File "G:\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "G:\Python36\lib\_strptime.py", line 528, in _strptime
    datetime_date(year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

What do I need to amend in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not totally clear what you are trying to do with the string manipulations, but you have a `datetime` object, and the right way to increment it is with `timedelta` objects as below.  Are you trying to do something different?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today()
print(today)

for additional_days in range(1, 7):
    new_day = today + timedelta(days=additional_days)
    print(new_day)
```

## Result:

```
2020-09-28 12:55:40.155671
2020-09-29 12:55:40.155671
2020-09-30 12:55:40.155671
2020-10-01 12:55:40.155671
2020-10-02 12:55:40.155671
2020-10-03 12:55:40.155671
2020-10-04 12:55:40.155671
```